# Is there a way to use a class/interface property as datatype

Tags: typescript

I'm interested to know, if there is a way, that you can use a property from an object as datatype.

**Example:**

I have an interface:

```js
 interface foo {
    bar: string;
}
```

and a function that should only accept `foo.bar` as parameter:

```js
function baz(bar: foo.bar) {
    // Add code here
}
```

This is shurely not working.

**Why do I need this?**

I have a project, where we have an API with many IDs and other duplicated stuff so that we had "some" confusion in the past.

So I want to fix this by allowing the function, that makes the API call, only to take in like `foo.bar` and not `baz.bar`.

I know, that i can create a datatype and use it, but it's a bit costly to do this vor each and every property of some interfaces.
(Sadly the API is not using only IDs...)

If you guys have a solution for that, please show me how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If both foo.bar and baz.bar are strings then what differentiates them? Do you have a list of strings that will be passed. You can make a type based on that

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can pass `foo` to the method and only use the property you need.